# custom ag-grid-filter using dropdown for filtering particular column using react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am working on a project which requires ag-grid-filter outside with dropdown which will filter out the result of one column.

I have tried to do this using react and redux form.

```html
<select id="ddl" className="custom-select" onChange={this.jsFunction(this)}>
    <option >Search category name</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

on change of the dropdown the value should be filtered out using react and ag-grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ability of ag-grid to do the [quick filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-quick/) which filters across all columns  and you can customize it to be applied for a specific column

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using ag-grid's [External Filters](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-external/)

Quick filter is preferred if you want to do a filter on entire grid and your comparator function will end up being complex if you want to filter from just one column.

In your html you can do `onChange={this.jsFunction($event.target.value)}`

```
jsFunction(filterVal) {
    this.filterVal= filterVal;
    gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged(); //this invokes your custom logic by forcing grid filtering
}

function doesExternalFilterPass(node) {
    if (this.filterVal) {
        return node.data.yourColumnValue === this.filterVal;
     }
    return true; //default case return all rows
   }
```

Lastly, update your grid configuration

```
isExternalFilterPresent: true,
doesExternalFilterPass: doesExternalFilterPass
```

you can find official example [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-external/#example-external-filter)